# How to add new properties to ICampaignActivityDefinition interface and deploy it in Sitecore 10

Tags: xdb, marketing-definitions, campaigncreator

We are upgrading the `Sitecore version from 8.2 to 10` and we have a few customizations in our projects related to campaign creation. In Sitecore 8.2 we use to have the `SaveCampaign` class present in the `Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.DeployDefinition` namespace which use to take care of the customization but in Sitecore 10 this class is not present and hence the implementation is not working. In Sitecore 10 it is mentioned to use Marketing operation API to deploy the campaign. As I am new to this, I am not able to understand which processor I need to alter to accomplish the same.
Right now I am trying the `Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt.Pipelines.DeployDefinition.Deploy` processor but not sure if it is the correct one.
Kindly help if anyone has worked on similar requirements or faced such challenges.
Any help or lead is appreciated.

Comment: Are having any issues when using Sitecore.Marketing.xMgmt.Pipelines.DeployDefinition.Deploy pipeline? It sounds correct.

Comment: Not having any issue with the deploy pipeline. Just want to know if we are doing some customization like adding few extra parameters to default campaign parameters, the how it should be save and which pipeline need to patch etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want code like this

```
Guid planId;
var manager = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetDefinitionManagerFactory().GetDefinitionManager<IAutomationPlanDefinition>();

var plan = manager.Get(planId, new CultureInfo("en"));
plan.Description = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
await manager.SaveAsync(plan);
```